# Swingbuilder constraints

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder

Most of the widgets in SwingBuilder have property called constraints.  How this is used in controlling the structure/layout.  Are there any other uses of this?

Also in the code behind, how the builder will translate the constraints into a logic that manipulates the layout.